# How to install Apk in Android studio and add tests using it?

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, apk, android-espresso

I am a beginner in Android UI automation. Have a few doubts but am not able to find any relevant information. All the tutorials have a source code and have no explanation on how to install your own app in Android studio and how to create the corresponding AndroidManifest.xml

Any input would be appreciated.

I tried using Build->Analyze APK and fetching my apk but not sure how to get the corresponding Android Manifest file and point my tests to start using the apk.

Comment: What do you want to do exactly, please write a proper description and you can install the app only on your device and emulator

Comment: The `Build->Analyze APK` option is used for analyzing your APK size